# Add CiviDiscount code "field" to a particular event on site

Tags: drupal, cividiscount

We are running several events and while I understand how to create the discount code for each event I am still wondering how one goes about adding the field, to the page, for the user to submit the code that was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That field just gets added to your Event Registration page if you've got everything configured properly!

Make sure you multi-select all Fields within all PriceSets (and or other options) that you'd like to attach the Discount to.

Comment: where does it add the field and is there any control over where it is placed?

Comment: It gets positioned right at the top of the page - to move it you'll need to add some jQuery.